# What does ?= do in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Looking through my `Makefile`, I see `SOMEVAR?=somestuff` and I'm not sure what that means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html), it sets `SOMEVAR` only if it is not currently defined with some other value.

Answer (score 5):

See the MAN-pages of `make`:

> VARIABLE ASSIGNMENTS
>        Variables in make are much like variables in the shell, and, by tradi-
>        tion, consist of all upper-case letters.
>
> Variable assignment modifiers
>        The five operators that can be used to assign values to variables are as
>        follows:
>
> ```
>  =       Assign the value to the variable.  Any previous value is overrid-
>          den.
>
>  +=      Append the value to the current value of the variable.
>
>  ?=      Assign the value to the variable if it is not already defined.
>
>  :=      Assign with expansion, i.e. expand the value before assigning it
>          to the variable.  Normally, expansion is not done until the vari-
>          able is referenced.  NOTE: References to undefined variables are
>          not expanded.  This can cause problems when variable modifiers
>          are used.
>
>  !=      Expand the value and pass it to the shell for execution and
>          assign the result to the variable.  Any newlines in the result
>          are replaced with spaces.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It assigns the value to `SOMEVAR` if it is not already defined.